# Is a static collection guaranteed to be initialized/populated before another class uses it?

Tags: c#, static

Suppose I have these 2 classes:

```
public class A<T> where T : IEntityWithID, new()
{
    private static EntityInfo entityInfo = B.GetEntityInfo(typeof(T));

    private static IEnumerable TestCases
    {
        // Do work with entityInfo...
    }
}

private static class B
{
    private static IList<EntityInfo> entityInfoList = B.GetEntityList();

    public static EntityInfo GetEntityInfo(Type type)
    {
       return entityInfoList.Single(e => e.Types.Contains(type));
    }

    private static IList<EntityInfo> GetEntityList()
    {
       // Builds a list of EntityInfo's...
    }
}
```

Is the entityInfoList in class B guaranteed to be initialized and populated before B.GetEntityInfo() is called in class A?

Comment: Where's `B.GetEntityInfo()`? You don't show it.

Comment: Added B.GetEntityInfo() definition...

Comment: How is `GetEntityList` built?

Comment: It's built by using reflection to get all types that contain an IEntityWithID interface. It then creates an EntityInfo object (custom defined class that contains information about a DB entity basically) for each type and adds it to the list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is guaranteed. Here's a snippet from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx):

> The program cannot specify exactly when the class is loaded. However,
>   it is guaranteed to be loaded and to have its fields initialized and
>   its static constructor called before the class is referenced for the
>   first time in your program.

EDIT: As pointed out, you could end up in a situation where 2 static classes depend on each other for initialization which could get you in trouble, but as long as that's not the case, you're fine.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: This is false.  It is in fact possible to get the value of such a field before the initializer has finished.

Comment: He didn't really ask about *finished*, just initialized (and populated). Your answer below shows that it does get initialized and populated, but there is a chance to overwrite that (after it happens).

Comment: @KeithPayne I demonstrated accessing the value of the field *before* it is initialized.  I never overwrite the value of that field.  I could even mark it as `readonly` and it wouldn't change the code.

Comment: There is an additional scenario here that isn't covered.  If the operation to build the static list occurs inside of a new thread, the order is obviously no longer guaranteed.  The MSDN documentation fails to reference this.

Comment: @Servy I did not fully understand your code below. Now I see it.

Comment: @Servy I guess you can take it up with the MSDN documentation staff. I've updated my answer to address the circular dependency scenario.

Comment: So now your answer simply contradicts itself.  You say yes, it's guaranteed, and then say no, it's not.  If you now realize that it cannot be guaranteed, then why are you saying that it is?

Comment: @Servy It's guaranteed except in the scenario described, that's why. Also, I don't think it contradicts itself. It says "yes, unless this specific thing is happening." That's not a contradiction. Also, you should make the classes in your answer `static` to increase relevancy.

Comment: @itsme86 When something is guaranteed except under certain circumstances, then it's not guaranteed.  That's what it means for something to be a guarantee.  It doesn't mean mostly, it means *always*.  As far as the classes being static, there's no reason for them to be static; the example works fine without it.  They could also be static and it would work, but it's designed to be a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @Servy I didn't say it didn't work without being static. I said to increase relevancy. The OP is talking directly about static classes. And yes, you absolutely can place qualifiers on a guarantee. Almost every guarantee has qualifers. Otherwise you couldn't guarantee anything. `int num = 42;` Oops bad stick of RAM, you guaranteed it would work!

Comment: The OP isn't asking about static classes, he's asking about static fields.  The question isn't asking about static classes at all.  As for guarantees, you can in fact make guarantees that aren't false.  That lots of people like to guarantee things that can then not happen doesn't change that; it just means that wasn't a guarantee.  If you realize that the statement in question won't always be true, then don't say that it will always be true.

Answer (score 4):

No, if you have circular dependencies it's possible to run code from a class before that class's static initialization has finished.

Here's a simple example of a static field initialized to `5`, and  yet an external class observes that field being `null`:

```
public class A
{
    public static void Foo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(B.bar == null);
    }
}

public class B
{
    public static readonly object bar = Foo();

    public static object Foo()
    {
        A.Foo();
        return 5;
    }
}

private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var bar = B.bar;
}
```

This will print `true`.

Comment: This is good to keep in mind (should not be downvoted), but doesn't answer the question directly. Perhaps an edit to explain that it is additional information?

Comment: @KeithPayne How does it *not* answer the question?  The question asks if it's guaranteed that the value is populated before the given method is called.  I showed how you can make it not be populated when calling the method, thus proving that the guarantee cannot be made.

Comment: I see what you mean. I did not fully understand your answer. But it still does not seem to be 100% on-point. The code in question doesn't contain a circular dependency. But in the abstract, it is a valid concern.

Comment: @KeithPayne The code in the quesiton is incomplete, and does not provide an implementation of any of the methods.  We have no idea if it has a circular dependency or not.  Given that there are possible implementations of those methods that would violate the guarantee, that guarantee cannot be made.